# JavaScript: Most efficient and performant way to partition ArrayBuffer memory

Tags: javascript, memory

I would compare what I am doing to what JavaScript runtimes already do, yet I'm doing it in JavaScript and Wasm. JavaScript implementations store JavaScript objects and values in actual computer heap memory, yet performing operations such as attempting to read/write out of bounds memory don't actually modify the memory (ex: arrays perform a no-op and return `undefined` respectively).

I'll give an example of my specific situation:

Let's say that I have an array buffer of 1000 bytes, we'll name the variable `memory`.

I want to split apart the buffer specifically into Int32Arrays of size 4. Each partition from the ArrayBuffer must do two things:

a) Refer to the original buffer (so that, when the original data is manipulated, the partition will update its values automaticially)

b) Not expose the original buffer (as the partition could then be used to corrupt the other partitions)

I have a function that determines which section is available for usage, we'll call it `findPartition`. It returns an integer acting as a pointer to a set of available bytes. (like C's malloc)

Each partition is expected to always remain the same type, that is, they will always be Int32Arrays if they start as an Int32Array, and their size will always be constant.

The script operating on the partition may both, write to, and read from, its partitioned array.

Originally, I was thinking that I could just call the Int32Array constructor on my array buffer, simply like so:

```js
const createPartition = () => new Int32Array( memory, findPartition(), 4 );
```

The problem is that the buffer is exposed, so I could either delete the `buffer` property.
But... the `buffer` property is readonly, so delete fails when used on the array.

I then thought that I could make a class to do this:

```js
class Partition {
    #source = new Int32Array( memory, findPartition(), 4 );

    get 0() { return this.#source[0]; }
    set 0(x) { this.#source[0] = x; }

    get 1() { return this.#source[1]; }
    set 1(x) { this.#source[1] = x; }

    get 2() { return this.#source[2]; }
    set 2(x) { this.#source[2] = x; }

    get 3() { return this.#source[3]; }
    set 3(x) { this.#source[3] = x; }

    get length() { return 4; }
};
```

Well, that works, but it's much more verbose, thus harder to maintain later, and, as the partitions are not given direct access to the indexes' values, because they have to go through getters and setters, I feel that performance could be lost.

Ideally, the Int32Array.prototype is also on the object, so I would have to wrap everything, which would be annoying and unmaintainable. If the spec updates the methods of the prototype, then I would have to update the wrappers too.

Does anyone have a better way to segment the array buffer, while maintaining safety between the segments?

Comment: If you value performance then you'll need to drop the "Not expose the original buffer" requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is one of the most important parts of this.
The underlying memory buffer must be completely opaque.
But really, the arrays are relatively useless without the common prototype operations, and maintaining wrappers is going to slow down everything. I'm looking for simplicity and development efficiency here. Although performance is very important.

Comment: I fail to see why having a `buffer` property that users are expected to respect as a private implementation detail is so important to avoid. And you've just reiterated the point I was trying to make: any workaround satisfying that constraint is necessarily going to be slower than the "most efficient and performant way", as your title requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to extend chosen typed array like that:

```js
// Seal and freeze hidden Object (TypedArray.prototype) that has methods
// that can leak original buffer if attacked using defineProperty tricks
// Since we can't directly access hidden Object on which `subarray`
// and many other methods defined we use this workaround
// Paranoid: More checks required to make sure that: `subarray` method; 'byteOffset',
// 'byteLength', 'buffer' getters; are not modified beforehand
Object.seal(Int8Array.__proto__.prototype);
Object.freeze(Int8Array.__proto__.prototype);


class customUint32Array extends Uint32Array {
  get buffer(){
      // copy! viewed array buffer segment
      // test if `super.` is faster/slower than `this.` access
      return super.buffer.slice(this.byteOffset, this.byteOffset + this.byteLength);
    // return super.buffer.slice(super.byteOffset, super.byteOffset + super.byteLength);
  }
}


// var customUint32ArrayOverWholeBufferCached = new customUint32Array(memory);
function Partition(){
  // test performance of `new` vs `customUint32ArrayOverWholeBufferCached.subarray`
  // for fastest array buffer view creation
  return new customUint32Array(memory, findPartitionByteOffset(), 4);
  // return customUint32ArrayOverWholeBufferCached.subarray(findPartitionIndex(), 4);
}
```

By the way 'private' class properties in most JS environments are exposed as any other property and will leak original buffer.

Prototype chains forged manually instead of `class X extends Y` are welcome in comments.
If one will pass my original buffer leak tests, I'll include it here.
Current instance' prototype chain looks something like: `customUint32Array.Uint32Array.TypedArray.prototype.Object`

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot. All that I needed was `get buffer() { .. }`, not `buffer = ...`, or `delete this.buffer`.
I didn't realize that the buffer was a getter, thank you!